# Cat losing fur on left side of her neck

Tags: cats, health, medicines, veterinarian, allergies

I have a cat that has been losing fur on her neck for the past month and I am really worried. The first time my cat lost fur on her neck was when I was fostering another cat and she ended up having a fever along with it. That was about a year ago, and she was doing fine since we sent away the foster cat, but she started losing fur again about a month ago on the same spot on her neck and on her chest as well. We took her to the vet and the doctor said that it might be allergies, so she advised us to only feed our cat wet/dry food and give her a bath so we did. After that, she started growing her fur back but at a really slow rate. Her fur was fine yesterday and I could see that almost all her fur grew back, but this morning I noticed that she's losing fur yet again in the same exact spot. I don't know what to do and I'd like to take her to the vet to take an actual test but it's probably going to be very expensive. I know the bald spot seems really small right now, but in the past it grew to be pretty large which is why I'm concerned. Does anyone know what could be causing her to lose fur in the same exact spot?

The first photo is her fur now and the second photo is her fur a month ago after she took a bath, which is why her fur is wet.

[image: The first photo is her fur now and the second photo is her fur a month ago after she took a bath, which is why her fur is wet.]

Comment: I don't think anyone here can challenge what the vet suggests, especially without examining the animal. The usual suspects are allergy or bugs. Once somewhere gets itchy, cats over scratch a location as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a possibility, but it could be scabies. My dogs were recently infested with them and the vet failed to catch it. The vet thought they just had allergies and treated them with Cytopoint. While that did help the scratching, it returned within a month. It wouldn’t hurt to ask the vet to check for scabies.

Scabies is a contagious skin condition caused by mites one the skin. They cause sever itching and a pimple-like rash. Your vet will have to take a skin sample from your can and examine it under a microscope. If your cat does have scabies, then your vet will prescribe a medication (topical or oral) to kill the mites and possibly a medicated antibacterial shampoo or antibiotics to prevent a skin infection. You will also need to thoroughly clean or replace your cat’s bed, collar, toys, etc.

This is a good article about various types of scabies and treatment in cats [Pets WebMD](https://pets.webmd.com/cats/cat-mange-scabies).